# Is the controller in Angular and ASP.NET MVC aimed to the same?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs

Is the controller in [Angular](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller) and [ASP.NET MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/aspnet-mvc-controllers-overview-cs) aimed to do the same like:

1. Consume services to shape the data (model) to return to the view.
2. Modal validation.

Comment: Elaborate...what are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1):

When dealing with architectures, it's very important to not confuse architecture with functionality.  The purpose of architecture is to **organize your functionality,** and *that's all it does.*  Doing so provides benefits like modularity and separation of concerns.  While these benefits are extremely important, a program that's well-architected but has little functionality invokes complexity for no discernible benefit.  I've seen programs like that: lots of ceremony, organization and structure, but most of the code doesn't do any actual work.  So be cautious about thinking about architecture before you've even decided what your program is supposed to accomplish.

That said, the primary purpose of the controller in any MV* architecture is to *separate the functionality from the presentation.*  That means you have a data store and your business logic on one side of the controller (your Model), and a user interface on the other side of the controller (your View).  The controller mostly acts as a go-between, a patch panel of sorts, and that's all it really does.  It provides a thin layer of separation between your UI and your functionality.

The way that this separation is provided differs between ASP.NET MVC and Angular.  In ASP.NET MVC, the controller marries an URL with a method call.  In Angular (MVVM), the controller sets up the initial state of the `$scope` object, and adds behavior to the `$scope` object.  But there are strict guidelines about what a controller can and cannot do.  The controller provides a mapping function, and that's all it does.  Everything else belongs either in the Model or the View.

You can find out more about how all this works by reading the material I link below.

**Further Reading**
[Understanding Angular Controllers](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller)
[Understanding ASP.NET MVC Controllers](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/aspnet-mvc-controllers-overview-cs)

Comment: I understand what you told about the *URL Method marriage* in the ASP.NET MVC controller where that wont be existing in the Angular MVVM. However, similar to the $scope in Angular, MVC also can return a model as movies list in this [example](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/accessing-your-models-data-from-a-controller). In both the cases, they are providing the data to the view. Since ASP.NET MVC does not have two way binding, it does not need a scope.

Comment: The controllers in both the cases help Separation Of Concerns, and do the same like shaping the data for the view.